Replacing a single pole light switch with a wireless module, but there are 3 wires
I have a light switch in the hallway to operate the attic lights. There is no switch in the attic but between the lights is a junction box for a fan if I decide to put one in. I went to replace the switch with a wireless module so I can control the lights from both hallway and while in the attic. However as shown in the sketch there are L and N power in to the switch and then to the lights there is a 3 conductor cable with a red wire. Now I am confused on how to connect the module. Any advice please would be great.


Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

It appears as black was treated as an always-on hot passthrough (maybe for the fan), and red was switched hot. You'll probably just use the black and white as per the instructions, disregarding red, which you can simply cap or leave connected to the source hot as it is now.
LINE      LOAD
black --> red
red ----> unused (leave disconnected or bundle with black, and cap)
white --> blue

Note that code may require that a manual switch be available, for safety on the stairs or ladder. You could install the controller alongside the switch and use the red conductor for it, leaving the black for the manual switch. This would allow override by the manual switch. Black and red could then be recombined at the lights.
